# Focus being lost behind nav bar when tabbing from bottom to top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome

For our intranet site we're using the [bootstrap nav bar](http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/navbar-tutorial.php) that stays in a fixed position at the top of the browser. On this particular page, the use is going to want to tab horizontally through two columns of input fields.

**Chrome**

In Chrome, however, when the user tabs from the bottom of one column to the top of the next, the browser accomodates the user by moving the scroll bar to the very top, thus allowing the user to see what field the focus is currently on. Here is a screen shot showing what I mean:

[image]

**Internet Explorer**

In IE, however (versions 8, 9, & 10) the input field is moved to the very top of the browser and gets lost behind the nav bar like so:

[image]

Is there a way to grammatically adjust the position of the IE scroll bar when the focus is set on the top input field of the second column?

Comment: Could you provide a link to test your issue?

Comment: Unfortunately it's an intranet site, so you wouldn't be able to access it unless you work for us ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you apply the class `first-input` to each input that causes this problem, then this JS/jQuery code might be helpful.

```
$(window).keyup(function(event) {              // Catch all keyboard events
  if (event.keyCode == 9) {                    // We only care about the TAB Key
    var $activeEl = $(document.activeElement); // Get the currently focused element
    if ($activeEl.hasClass('first-input')) {   // If the element is a first-input...
      console.log("We hit a first-input, adjust scroll.");
      $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() - 50);     // Adjust scroll
    }                                                      // You can increase the number
  }
});
```

There's probably a way to check if it's the first input (besides using a hard coded class name) — but that was the quickest thing that came to mind.

Comment: This works fine in Chrome (again), but in IE I get this error: `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'apply'`